# How do you analyse "using" in this sentence "Upload your video to YouTube or vimeo using .mov, .Avi, or a .Mpg file."?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, relative-clauses

How do you analyse "using" in this sentence

> Listen to this,
>   "Cover letters are so old-fashioned.
>   Show us who you are with a cover-letter video.
>   Upload your video to YouTube or Vimeo **using .mov, .avi,
>   or a .mpg file.**"
>   We look forward to meeting you.
>   Well, I guess that's meeting me.
>   I swear I don't even know what language that was.

Source: [The Intern (2015) Movie Script](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=the-intern)

I would think the complete sentence is:

"*Upload your video to YouTube or vimeo **that use** .mov, .Avi, or a .Mpg file.*"

And that usage is "reduced relative clause"

But I am not sure

Comment: No, "using" there is equivalent to "by using" and expresses the manner in which you can upload the video. It introduces an adverbial of manner.

Comment: but then why they omitted "**by**"

Comment: It means the same thing, with or without "by". Read PARTICIPLES USED AS ADVERBS here: https://www.thoughtco.com/present-and-past-participles-explained-1211104

Comment: **using** is not the best word to use here, as it implies that the file format is simply a tool in to upload process. The file format is a characteristic of the video, and so **as** would be more appropriate. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/, preposition meaning 1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a poorly worded sentence.

Comment: @JavaLatte, this sentence is said by Robert De Niro, in the film "The Intern 2015"

Comment: @JavaLatte: It's not *that* bad; in fact, it's a perfectly reasonable thing a native speaker might say, and rejecting questions about utterances from native speakers because they're "poorly worded" is unhelpful prescriptivism.

Comment: Does that make it OK then, Tom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this source](https://www.thoughtco.com/present-and-past-participles-explained-1211104)

> PARTICIPLES USED AS ADVERBS
>
> The present participle is sometimes used as an adverb to describe the
>   manner in which a verb is performed. Here are a few examples:
>
> She taught pounding the grammar into their heads!
>
> Angelo works considering all angles.
>
> Notice how the present participle could be preceded with 'by' to give
>   the same meaning:
>
> She taught (by) pounding the grammar into their heads!
>
> Angelo works (by) considering all angles.

And that answered  my question:

**Upload your video to YouTube or Vimeo *(by)* using .mov, .avi, or a .mpg file.**

Comment: You say YOU found it?